# Value too long or small error when parsing int

Tags: c#

When i am trying to save a int value on entity framework i am getting following error-

> System.OverflowException: 'Value was either too large or too small for
>   an Int32.'

Note the value is something like- 9093739202727

Is there any better way then that to process that value?

[image: pic]

Code:

```
if (result.responseCode.ToString() == "APPROVED")
{
    var sub = new Subscriptions();
    sub.UserEmail = result.merchantOrderId;
    sub.SaleNumber = Int32.Parse(result.orderNumber.ToString());
    sub.LastTransectionId = Int32.Parse(result.transactionId.ToString());
    sub.LastUpdatedTime = DateTime.Now;
    if (twoCheckout.ProductTypeId == "m")
    {
        sub.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);
    }else if (twoCheckout.ProductTypeId == "y")
    {
        sub.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1);
    }
    sub.Status = false;
    db.Subscriptions.Add(sub);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Int64.Parse` ? It returns a `long`. I'm guessing `Subscriptions.SaleNumber` is an int, which will be a problem because it can't store values that large.

Comment: Yes Subscriptions.SaleNumber is int. I want to convert this to int thats why. This is not possible? Int64.Parse gives same error

Comment: really? `var i = Int64.Parse("9093739202727");` works on my machine.

Comment: https://ibb.co/ekQqGb check screen shot when i try to do int64

Comment: Call `toString()` on `result.orderNumber`. However, its already a `long?`, so why parse it at all? Check if it has a value, and if so, use it.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kmSLGb something like that?

Comment: If you know it has a value, you can assign it like `sub.SaleNumber = result.orderNumber.Value` but that will fail if orderNumber turns out to be `null`.

Comment: https://ibb.co/cmmBpw no bro no luck haha

Comment: But what do you expect? It is not possible to hold the `long` value `9093739202727` inside an `int`. And do you know it is never `null`. You can do `sub.SaleNumber = (int)(result.orderNumber);`, however it will fail if the `orderNumber` is null, and it will remove the most significant bits of your number. In this case it will be `1293437095` for positive `long` `9093739202727`. I doubt that is what you want?

Comment: Aside from anything else, any conversion you want to do is unlikely to be related to a string representation - so don't do a conversion. It's very rarely a good idea to convert something to a string just to parse it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#'s `int` range is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. You're going to need a `long` or better off a `double` to handle values that large.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int

Comment: Ok. whatever how can i parse it to store on database? any example?

Comment: (Assuming Microsoft SQL Server) Instead of an `int` column in your database table, use a `float`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx

Comment: Rather than a .NET `double` or a SQL Server `float`, it seems more appropriate with a .NET `long` (a.k.a. `System.Int64`) which corresponds to a SQL Server `bigint`.